# Is it possible to store multiple types of arrays within one array of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array, types

I am currently working on a project where I get a set of data from an XML file. The XML file has multiple node that store different data types (strings, ints and bools). Java returns each of these as a string which is fine because you can convert them into the proper data types within the program. As the nodes are returned I want to put them into an array of proper type and store each of those arrays in a master array for later use in my program. In my XML file I would like to have a node where there can be multiple child nodes with the same tag which is why I am using a multi-dimensional array.

I have attempted using an `Object[][]` and `Variable[][]` to no success, unless I am missing something simple (which could be the case).

XML example:

```
<parent>
    <child1>string</child1>
    <child2>int</child2>
    <child2>int</child2>
    <child3>boolean</child3>
</parent>
```

Java example:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parent");
NodeList nlAttributes = nList.item(cardId).getChildNodes();
List<String> lElements = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> lRepeateElement = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i <nlAttributes.getLength(); i++){
    if(nlAttributes.item(i).getNodeType()!=3&&nlAttributes.item(i).getNodeType()!=8){
        if(nlAttributes.item(i).getNodeName().equals("effect")){
            lRepeateElement.add(nlAttributes.item(i).getTextContent());
        }else{
            lElements.add(nlAttributes.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
aRepeatElements = new String[lRepeateElement.size()];
for(int i = 0; i<lRepeateElement.size(); i++){
    aRepeatElements[i]=lRepeateElement.get(i);
}
sElements = new String[lElements.size()];
oElements = new Variable[lElements.size()+1][]; //oElements = new Object[lElements.size()+1][];
for(int i = 0; i<lElements.size(); i++){
    if(i==4){
        oElements[i]=aRepeatElements;//incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to Variable/Object[] -> this still exists after attempting to casts
    }else{
        sElements[i]=lElements.get(0);
        String[] temp = new String[1];
        temp[0]=sElements[i];//incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to Variable/Object[] -> this still exists after attempting to casts
        oElements[i]=temp;
        lElements.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Object[][] should work after converting `int` to `Integer` (and similarly for other primitives).

Comment: Yup that worked... like I said above, something simple that I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to know :-) ... converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: Thanks, was looking at your profile page trying to find out how to give you credit for answering this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object[][]` will solve the problem because everything in Java is an `Object`. Everything except the primitives, that is!

To overcome that issue, all you need to do is wrap the primitives:

- `int` --> `Integer`
- `boolean` --> `Boolean`
- ...